# Why Array(x).map doesn't return the correct object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why `Array(5).map((x, i) => ({id: i, value: 0}))` returns an empty array of lenght 10 but `[0,0,0,0,0].map((x, i) => ({id: i, value: 0}))` return an array with the correct object?

```js
console.log('Array(5)', Array(5).map((x, i) => ({id: i, value: 0})))
console.log('[0,0,0,0,0]', [0,0,0,0,0].map((x, i) => ({id: i, value: 0})))
```

Comment: map does not work for sparse elements.

Comment: [That's the way it's defined to work.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: `Array(5)` contains `5` empty stops. They are not actual `undefined` values.

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log('Array(5)', Array(5).fill().map((x, i) => ({id: i, value: 0})))
console.log('[0,0,0,0,0]', [0,0,0,0,0].map((x, i) => ({id: i, value: 0})))
```

Check what `Array.fill()` does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Comment: A short summary of what fill does would make this answer much better